# Is it possible that I unrooted my device after changing the build.prop?

Tags: rooting, unrooting, supersu

I had rooted my device, I have Titanium Backup, Superuser, and ES File Explorer.

I changed the android version, phone model and sdk version in the build.prop file. Now I can't open any app other than Titanium Backup, which tells me it wasn't granted superuser permissions, and that I should check if my ROM is rooted.

When I access the files through my computer with Android Studio, I can see the root files.

Is my phone not rooted anymore or is Superuser just not working properly due to the build.prop change?

Comment: Most likely your changes (e.g. the Android version) broke something in a component of Android which is used by Superuser and other apps.

Comment: You could restore the original `build.prop` using the root powers of the custom recovery installed – of course provided there are such things as "backup" and "custom recovery"…

Answer (score 1):

So yeah, it turns out my device was always rooted. As Robert said, I probably broke something that SuperSU used.

If anyone finds this helpful, I got it back to normal through recovery, like Izzy said.

I had previously backed up the build.prop file to my SDcard, so I created a zip file with `build.prop` and a `meta-inf` folder that I found in a custom ROM (I actually found it in this question from the XDA forum https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/copy-build-prop-with-flashable-zip.2986827/
However, this https://www.reddit.com/r/FirmwareDevelopment/comments/1iut7m/howto_understanding_the_metainf_folder_for/ says you can get it from any custom ROM). Flashed the zip file through CWM recovery and after rebooting, my phone was acting like nothing ever happened c:

*If you didn't backup `build.prop`, I'm sure there's ways to retrieve it through ADB, pretty sure you can copy it and paste it somewhere. Either way, you can still see the content of the file in Android Studio, and I'm guessing Eclipse and other programs I don't know of; and I'm a n00b, but I'm pretty sure you can make a brand new build.prop by copying the contents of the existing one on a text editor, of course changing what you had previously modified, hence leaving it the way it was before you messed it up.